# Icons in PaginationToolbar not showing up

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4

I'm using the Sencha ExtJS Framework in Version 4.05 and i have the following problem. I am displaying Ext.Grids which have a pagination toolbar at the bottom of the Grid. On the Sencha Sample Page the Grids will display some buttons (first-page, prev-page, next-page, last-page, refresh) with icons on it.

Unfortunately the icons are not displayed in my Grids:

[image: The Pagination Toolbar]

As you can see, the buttons are actually there, and they're working correcrly, only the icons are not displayed.

The references to the images are correct and the images are there and accessible for the browser. (If i view the css of the button in Firebug and hover the imageurl it will display the correct icon).

One thing i noticed is, that for some reason the `<span>` Element which should display the icon is "grayed out" in the firebug view. (On the Sencha example page it is not).

[image: The Part of the DOM corresponding to the Refresh button]

The CSS of that element looks fine for me:

[image: The CSS of the span element]

**Note**: The complete CSS File used can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/1322046)

A short note on the Theme: i made this grey theme (named "documents") just by changing the main colour of the .sass template and compiling the ext-all.css to a new one for my theme. So i didn't change anything with the icons.

Any suggestions what could cause this problem?

Comment: can you post a working example so I can take a proper look?

Comment: clueless.. is it behave the same cross browser?

Comment: In order to show grayed in Firebug the element must somehow have the style display:none applied to it. Can you post the styles applied to the span#button-1057-btnIconEl as shown by Firebug?

Comment: Jaitsu: Unfortunately i cannot post an example i don't really know how i could do that with extjs. Lionel Chan: Yes it's same in IE7, FF4, Chrome. Marco Miltenburg: The styles in the image are the styles that apply to span#button-1057-btnIconEl. They're not the styles of the marked button element.

Comment: How about testing this with change of version? Extjs 4.0.7 if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to debug without access to the actual code. However, I noticed that both in the CSS you copied above as well as the css link you posted (which was supposedly the whole css), that neither set of css (that I could find) had any reference to the `x-btn-icon` class by itself, and yet that is the class (along with `x-tbar-loading`) that is on your grayed out span element. So, what is that class doing? Where is it defined? There may reside your issue.

EDIT: I went to the Sencha website and firebugged an icon on the grid sample. When I deleted the `x-btn-icon` class from the element, I believe I duplicated your problem. So it seems that the necessary definition of that class is missing from your css. On their site it is defined in the ext-all.css.

Comment: Thank you for the research! Obviously that was exactly the problem. This styles were missing, because i was using ExtJS 4.0.5 and these styles were just not present in the sass files i compiled my theme from. So it was an error in ExtJS Version 4.0.5. I recompiled my styles with Ext 4.0.7 and it works fine now!